# Count Number of Users in Cassandra column family?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cqlsh

I have a table like this in Cassandra-

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_HOLDER (USER_ID TEXT, RECORD_NAME TEXT, RECORD_VALUE BLOB, PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID, RECORD_NAME));
```

I want to count distinct USER_ID in my above table? Is there any way I can do that?

My Cassandra version is:

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.10.71 | DSE 4.5.2 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select expression is defined as:

```
selection_list
 | DISTINCT selection_list
```

so you can:

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID FROM DATA_HOLDER;
```

Comment: Well Cassandra internally has a limitation that it will return these many rows? How do I solve that? This query will not return full rows we have in cassandra.

Comment: If you have 10s of thousands you should do it with spark or use a counter to keep it up to date (or a combination of the 2).